# how to parse this json throgh volly?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i get this error

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

```
 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //getting the whole json object from the response
                try {

```
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("helper", "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

//creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

```
    //adding the string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

[
    {
        "error": "false",
        "code": "200",
        "message": "Operation Successfully.",
        "no_of_records": 3,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "broker_type_id": "1",
                "title": "Broker 1",
                "slug": "broker-1",
                "about": "Broker 1 about",
                "opening_balance": null,
                "closing_balance": null,
                "balance_total": null,
                "rating": null,
                "no_of_deal": null,
                "cnic": null,
                "status": "Active",
                "order_by": null,
                "created_by_comp_id": "5",
                "created_by_user_id": "1",
                "updated_by_user_id": null,
                "deleted_by_user_id": null,
                "created_at": "2019-08-02 23:55:39",
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "broker_type_id": "1",
                "title": "Broker 2",
                "slug": "broker-2",
                "about": "Broker 2 About",
                "opening_balance": null,
                "closing_balance": null,
                "balance_total": null,
                "rating": null,
                "no_of_deal": null,
                "cnic": null,
                "status": "Active",
                "order_by": null,
                "created_by_comp_id": "5",
                "created_by_user_id": "1",
                "updated_by_user_id": null,
                "deleted_by_user_id": null,
                "created_at": "2019-08-03 01:24:37",
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "broker_type_id": "1",
                "title": "Broker 4",
                "slug": "broker-4",
                "about": "Broker 4 about",
                "opening_balance": null,
                "closing_balance": null,
                "balance_total": null,
                "rating": null,
                "no_of_deal": null,
                "cnic": null,
                "status": "Active",
                "order_by": null,
                "created_by_comp_id": "5",
                "created_by_user_id": "1",
                "updated_by_user_id": null,
                "deleted_by_user_id": null,
                "created_at": "2019-08-03 11:46:54",
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: Do you mean volly? ->https://developer.android.com/training/volley

Comment: Parsing JSON on Android without using the help of converter is time-consuming. Parse any JSON using a converter (eg. GSON).
You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ link to make your model class.